# Formatting a header in an Emacs function to print a buffer to PDF w/ line wrapping

Tags: emacs, pdf-generation, elisp

Rupert Swarbrick came up with the following three functions to print an Emacs buffer to pdf in which lines are wrapped (this is not normally the case when using `ps-print*` functions).

The problem is this function is that to achieve this line wrapping, a copy of the current buffer has to be made. This effectively breaks the capability of `ps-print-buffer-with-faces` to display a correct header on top of each page in the resulting PDF file.

As part of his solution, Rupert Swarbrick wrote a function that preserves this information. The resulting header, however, is always **HeaderLinesLeft**

Who can spot the mistake?

```
(defun harden-newlines ()
  (interactive)
  "Make all the newlines in the buffer hard."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\n" nil t)
      (backward-char)
      (put-text-property (point) (1+ (point)) 'hard t)
      (forward-char))))

(defun spool-buffer-given-name (name)
  (load "ps-print")
  (let ((tmp ps-left-header))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn
          (setq ps-left-header
                (list (lambda () name) 'ps-header-dirpart))
          (ps-spool-buffer-with-faces))
      (setf ps-left-header tmp))))

(defun print-to-pdf ()
  "Print the current file to /tmp/print.pdf"
  (interactive)
  (let ((wbuf (generate-new-buffer "*Wrapped*"))
        (sbuf (current-buffer)))
    (jit-lock-fontify-now)
    (save-current-buffer
      (set-buffer wbuf)
      (insert-buffer sbuf)
      (setq fill-column 95)
      (longlines-mode t)
      (harden-newlines)
      (message (buffer-name sbuf))
      (spool-buffer-given-name (buffer-name sbuf))
      (kill-buffer wbuf)
      (switch-to-buffer "*PostScript*")
      (write-file "/tmp/print.ps")
      (kill-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (call-process "ps2pdf14" nil nil nil
                  "/tmp/print.ps" "/tmp/print.pdf")
    (delete-file "/tmp/print.ps")
    (message "PDF saved to /tmp/print.pdf")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun spool-buffer-given-name (name)
  (let ((ps-left-header (list (format "(%s)" name))))
    (ps-spool-buffer-with-faces)))
```

See documentation for variable ps-left-header, which is what clued me in to the above.

This is a neat capability; I'll definitely use it instead of ps-print.  It would be good to make it act more like C-u M-x ps-print-buffer-with-faces; two missing features are directory name in the header, and prompting the user for a filename.  Neither is too difficult.

Comment: Hi Rory. Thanks for your reply. Do I replace `spool-buffer-given-name` entirely or do I need to alter it?

Comment: Hi Werner.  You can just replace it with mine; it's equivalent.  The effect of unwind-protect/setf is more easily achieved (in this case, anyway) with let.  I'm not sure why the lambda was necessary.  As disclaimer, this version (combined with the code you posted) works fine on my Emacs 23.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: I just wanted to create a comment with two related posts:  The initial code by Rupert Swarbrick:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362625/word-wrap-for-emacs-print-buffer-to-pdf  And, the second follow-up:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779882/save-buffer-as-a-pdf-with-ns-write-file-using-panel-or-similar-option  I still need to implement opening the panel, but it almost does what I'm looking for.